# Creating Servicebus topics and adding a "User Description" using Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline, azureservicebus

I'll try to keep this short.
Summary of my problem:

I can successfully use a pipeline in my Azure DevOps to automatically create a Servicebus topic, subscription and queue.

I can add "rules" to my subscriptions without issues.

--
I want to add a "User Description" to my topic but I can't seem to get the data where it should go.
I'll post my code below as text and I'll also imbed a picture.
Thankful for any help in solving this issue. If it's not possible at this time then that would be helpful to know as well.

```
"parameters": {
    "namespaceName": { "value": "MyServiceBusName" },
    "namespaceResourceGroup" : { "value": "MyResourceGroup" },
    "subscriptions": {
        "value": [
            {
                "topicName": "TopicForTestPurposes",
                "subscriptionName": "SubscriptionForTestPurposes",
                "queueName": "QueueForTestPurposes",
                "ruleName": "ruleContainingRules",
                "sqlExpression": "name=myname'"
            },
            {
                "topicName": "TopicForTestPurposes",
                "subscriptionName": "SubscriptionForTestPurposes",
                "queueName": "QueueForTestPurposes",
                "ruleName": "ruleContainingOtherRules",
                "sqlExpression": "name='yourname'"
            }
        ]
    },
    "topics": {
        "value": [
            {
                "name": "TopicForTestPurposes",
                "description": "This is me testing a description",
                "rbac": [],
                "policies": []
            }
        ]
    },
    "queues": {
        "value": [
            {
                "name": "QueueForTestPurposes",
                "rbac": [],
                "policies": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image: This is my pipeline code]

[image: This is where I want the description in my ServiceBus]

Comment: Looking at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.servicebus/namespaces/topics?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template), I don't see the property "User Description". After some searching, I didn't see any relevant information either.